# Status not changing on button press

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, boolean

Whenever I presses the button, it should change text, and also change boolean value, yet this is not working. Any help? Thnks

Before onCreate:

```
public boolean status = false;
```

Button Click:

```
case R.id.saveButton:   

if (status != true) {
    currentStatus.setText("Current status: In need of help!");
    status = true;
}
if (status != false) {
    currentStatus.setText("Current status: Fine.");
    status = false;
}
break;
```

Comment: why != false? put status directly in `if`

Comment: Please post more code...

Comment: we need more information. How is this code called? Does your text change? Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: After the 1st `if` block, the status is changed to true. But in the second `if` block, the status is false again. So does the `currentStatus` text. Maybe, you should use `else` instead of the 2nd `if`

Comment: so, status != or status == does not make any difference, but better syntax is ==. But that´s not the problem here, follow darpans answer, its correct

Comment: Check if you called the setOnClickListener on your button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(status){
       currentStatus.setText("Current status: Fine.");
       status = false;
}else {                             
       currentStatus.setText("Current status: In need of help!");
       status = true
}
```

or using ternary operator :

```
currentStatus.setText(status ? "Current status: Fine." : "Current status: In need of help!");
status = !status;//toggle boolean value
```

Comment: Happens, we are mortals you see.

Comment: Thanks for adding code Sergey, though I have heard that one should avoid ternary operators. Well, that will comprise another question.

Answer (score 1):

if condition work boolean state so when check if condition using boolean variable no need to use == or != operator simple put boolean variable in if small bracket :

```
if(status){
 // this code executed when status is value is - true 
}else{
 // this code executed when status is value is - false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
you actually change your status twice in your code.

```
    case R.id.saveButton:   

            if(status == false){
                currentStatus.setText("Current status: In need of help!");

                status = true;

            }
            else if(status == true){
                currentStatus.setText("Current status: Fine.");
                status = false;

            }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified Code : you have to use `else` after first `if` statement in your code.

```
        boolean status = false;

        System.out.println("status : "+status); // False

         if(status != true){
             status = true;
         }else if(status != false){   // add else here to resolve issue
             status = false;
         }

         System.out.println("status : "+status); // True
```

Comment: please add some description with piece of your code

Comment: @SilentKiller your suggestion is appreciated ! I have added description in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't call the setOnClickListener on your button.

Implement **View.OnClickListener** interface

```
Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And in

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  if(status){
     currentStatus.setText("Current status: Fine.");
     status = false;
  }else {                             
     currentStatus.setText("Current status: In need of help!");
     status = true
  }
}
```